# Third Mertens theorem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I considered $\displaystyle\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ to find the lower bound of this expression.

Now we could use $\displaystyle \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim\frac{1}{\zeta'(1)}$, where $\displaystyle \zeta'(1) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$.

As we know : $\displaystyle \zeta'(1) \sim \log n + \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})$, so we get :

$\displaystyle \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim\frac{1}{\log n + \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})}$, but third Merten's theorem states :

$\displaystyle\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\log \log n}$.

I just want to prove that this product greater than $\displaystyle\frac{C}{\log \log n}$, for some constant $C$. I understand that the worst scenario will be when $\displaystyle n = \prod_{p|n} p^{1}$, and we could represent this equation as: 
$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sum_{p|n} \log p + \gamma}$, but that doesn't give me anything. Any hints, please.

Comment: $\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ strongly depends on the factorization of $n$, how can it be $\sim$ to a universal constant? However, if you know that $\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{1}{p}\sim\log\log(x)$, then $\prod_{p\leq x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\approx\exp\sum_{p\leq x}-\frac{1}{p}\approx\frac{C}{\log x}.$

Comment: Okay, is it true: $\displaystyle \prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \ge \frac{1}{\log n + \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})}$?
And I don't know why $\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log x$...